# Combining Classes through Methods in Java

Tags: java, ms-word

I have two working classes that function independently. I want to combine them, yet I have no working location to add a `public void (String Name){`. I keep getting a "remove this" or "Add }".

Code I have:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class WordDocument extends JFrame {
private JButton btnOpen;
private JLabel jLabel1;
private JTextField txtDocNumber;
public void SystemFiles() {
private static String DIR  ="c:\\Users\\tyler's account\\folders\\JavaReaderFiles\\";   // folder where word documents are present.
public WordDocument() {
   super("Open Word Document");
   initComponents();
} 
private void initComponents() {
    jLabel1 = new JLabel();
    txtDocNumber = new JTextField();
    btnOpen = new JButton();

    Container c = getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setText("Enter Document Number  : ");
    c.add(jLabel1);

    txtDocNumber.setColumns(5);
    c.add(txtDocNumber);

    btnOpen.setText("Open Document");
    btnOpen.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {      // anonymous inner class 
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
              Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();  
          try {
            File f = new File( DIR + txtDocNumber.getText()  +  ".doc");
             desktop.open(f);  // opens application (MSWord) associated with .doc file
          }
          catch(Exception ex) {
            // WordDocument.this is to refer to outer class's instance from inner class
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(WordDocument.this,ex.getMessage(),"Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
          }
        }
    });

    c.add(btnOpen);


}
public static void main(String args[]) {
      WordDocument wd = new WordDocument();
      wd.setSize(300,100);
      wd.setVisible(true);



                           }
}
```

I don't know where to add the Method. I have tried changing Private/Public classes and kept receiving multiple errors. I need this to run as a part of an IF loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
public void SystemFiles() {
```

It looks like you started this method but didn't close it with `}` and didn't add any body to it.

Comment: @TylerSchroder, also, fix your indentation.  Bad indentation is exactly why this sort of problem is hard to spot.

Comment: @Eran I have tried that, however, It throws off every other }.